# Where is documented all the basic members of a contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

It seems every contract instance has a member `balance`, as per Solidity [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function):

> It also means that `this.balance` can be higher than the sum of some manual accounting implemented in a contract (i.e. having a counter updated in the fallback function).

Where is documented all the members of this base contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special variables and functions can be found in the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=special#special-variables-and-functions).

This covers:

- [Block and transaction properties](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=special#block-and-transaction-properties)
- [Error handling](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=special#error-handling)
- [Mathematical and crytographic functions](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=special#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions)
- [Address related](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=special#address-related)
- [Contract related](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=special#contract-related)

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html) (link to official doc) might interest you